# Power BI : Split Comma Separated Values into Filter List

Tags: powerbi

I have this data that is loaded into my PowerBI

```
ID Color Group                       SubGroup
1  Blue  Clothes,Furniture,Kitchen   Men,Women
2  Red   Electronics,Clothes         All
3  Pink  Books,Clothes,Kitchen       Women,Girls,Baby
4  Black Electronics,Books,Furniture Men,Women,Boys,Girls
```

I want my Filter to show this list

**Filter 1**

```
Groups
-----------
Clothes
Furniture
Kitchen
Electronics
Books
```

**Filter 2**

```
SubGroups
-----------
Men
Women
Girls
Baby
Boys
All
```

so when user tick Clothes box in the Filter 1, all records will be filtered to the ones that has Clothes in its Group.

when user tick Women box in the Filter 2, all records will be filtered to the ones that has Women in its Subgroup.

How can I achieve that?

I tried filtering by Group and Subgroup directly but I got this in the filter

**Filter 1**

```
Groups
-----------
Clothes,Furniture,Kitchen
Electronics,Clothes
Books,Clothes,Kitchen
Electronics,Books,Furniture
```

**Filter 2**

```
SubGroups
-----------
Men,Women
All
Women,Girls,Baby
Men,Women,Boys,Girls
```

which is not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query editor, select your group/sub-group column, choose split column >> by Delimiter

[image]

Now choose a comma as the delimiter, and in advanced select split into rows:
[image]

You can use the resultant columns as slicer/filter:

[image]