# PowerBI - Using a Slicer to Filter Data Within a List in a Table

Tags: list, powerbi, slicers

In my PBI dashboard, I have a table which looks like this:

| Countries | Studies |
| --- | --- |
| Australia, Argentina, Belgium | Study1 |
| Argentina, Belgium, Poland | Study2 |
| Austria, Argentina | Study3 |

I was wondering if it was possible in any way to create a slicer to sit on the same page as this table, and when a certain country is selected it return the studies involved. i.e. using slicer I select 'Belgium' and it returns only Study1 and Study2 from the table.

I want this to able be available for multi-select, so using the slicer to select more than one country value.

I am no expert in PBI so please be as specific as possible in your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slicer to search for a specific string in a column - Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500161/slicer-to-search-for-a-specific-string-in-a-column-power-bi)

Comment: Also [Split Comma Separated Values into Filter List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404332).

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly - Not exactly, the answer posted was perfect for what I needed! Than you for suggesting that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Power BI, go to `Transform data` in the Home tab in the ribbon. This will open Power Query Editor.
- Find your query/table of that table.
- Right-click on the `Countries` column header, and select `Duplicate Column`. In the formula bar, rename it from `Countries - Copy` to `Country`.
- Right-click on the new `Country` column header and select `Split Column` > `By Delimiter...`. In the window that pops up, Expand `Advanced option` and select Split into `Rows`.
- Right-click on the `Country` column header, select `Transform` > `Trim`.

You should have a table looking like this:
[image]

Close and apply the Power Query window. Then back in main Power BI, you can use the new `Country` column for your Slicer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great solution. I have a follow up question - will this also work for new data? As I have set it up so that the query pulls in data from Airtable (which is going to be updated regularly)

Comment: Yes, it will work for new data.