# PowerBi Relationship with variable text

Tags: powerbi

I have the below list of vehicles.

[image]

I then have the below list of vehicles with IVMS breaches. (speeding etc)

[image]

I need to use PowerBi to list the IVMS breaches but filter by the customers/contract.

I envision a slicer with the customers listed and as I change the slicer the IVMS breaches updates.

My list of breaches is a simple table of "Date" "Vehicle" "Breach" "Count".

Example: 07/01/2024 ABC001 SPEED 5

I need to be able to filter the trucks based on the customer/contract.

Any help would be appreciated!! :)

Comment: Hi @Jamie, there's a better place to ask Power BI questions, directly on the PBI community https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-BI-forums/ct-p/powerbi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerBI - Using a Slicer to Filter Data Within a List in a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461441/powerbi-using-a-slicer-to-filter-data-within-a-list-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of composed values as:

```
CUSTOMER001, CUSTOMER004, CUSTOMER005
```

Would bring complexity to the model.

As best practices, decompose this type of values as only 1 value in the way that for each vehicle only exists only 1 customer, if the vehicle is repeating as a duple with the customer, that's fine. And if even this is duplicating for some reason, add other attribute like date, so this duple only happens once in that date if that's he case.

And that needs to happen in the ETL phase, so you need to transform this type of values and decomplex in simple values.

Then, you can build a simple relationship between the vehicles and the contracts in a easier manner. And remember, in PBI you can build as much tables as needed, despite those tables don't exist in the source data set.

Good luck with your engagement with PBI.